# Using GROUP BY CTE and JOINS in

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this, named `Tour Details`.

| dealdate | Tours | Weeknumber | Country | SubVenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-12 | 3 | 49 | India | SP1 |
| 2022-11-25 | 4 | 48 | India | SP2 |
| 2022-10-14 | 5 | 42 | India | SP3 |
| 2023-01-05 | 3 | 2 | India | SP1 |
| 2023-01-05 | 4 | 2 | India | SP2 |
| 2023-01-06 | 5 | 2 | US | SP1 |
| 2023-02-24 | 3 | 9 | US | SP2 |
| 2022-02-12 | 4 | 7 | US | SP3 |
| 2023-02-19 | 5 | 8 | US | SP1 |
| 2023-02-27 | 6 | 10 | US | SP2 |

I need to create a table.
This table should have information like

| Grp | Total Tours |
| --- | --- |
| Tours SP1 | 16 |
| Tours SP2 | 17 |
| Tours SP3 | 19 |

I have tried :

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 'Tours ' +SubVenue AS Grp
  FROM Tour_Details
)
SELECT CTE.Grp
    , SUM(T.Tours) AS Total   
FROM Tour_Details T
LEFT JOIN CTE  ON CTE.Grp = T.SubVenue 
GROUP BY  CTE.Grp, T.SubVenue
```

But the output I get is:

| Grp | Total Tours |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | 16 |
| NULL | 17 |
| NULL | 19 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why does `SP3` have a value of `19` for the `SUM`? Why are you using a CTE and (`LEFT`) `JOIN`? Isn't this just a simple `SUM`?

Comment: You are joining Tour_Details.SubVenue which has value like `SP1, SP2`  with `CTE.Grp` which has value like `Tours SP1, Tours SP2`. You will not get any matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this `SELECT 'Tours ' + SubVenue AS Grp FROM Tour_Details`
your `Grp` equals `Tours SP1` and you try to join it to `SubVenue` which equals `SP1`. `Tours SP1` <> `SP1`. You need to have the equals values in columns which you use in join.

And you can do it simpler.

```
SELECT
    'Tours ' +SubVenue AS Grp, 
    SUM(Tours) AS Total
FROM Tour_Details
GROUP BY 'Tours ' +SubVenue
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using a simple aggregation query :

```
select 'Tours ' + SubVenue as Grp, sum(Tours) as [Total Tours]
from Tour_Details
group by SubVenue
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over-thinking your problem, you just need a simple aggregation:

```
select Grp, sum(tours) Total_Tours
from Tour_Details
cross apply (values(Concat('Tours ', SubVenue))) g (Grp)
group by Grp;
```

Comment: Probably better to `GROUP BY SubVenue` and then `CONCAT` only in the `SELECT`, so that you can use indexes properly

Answer (score -3):

I think your SQL is failing because you are concatenating the string 'Tour ' with the contents of the subvenue field then using that concatenated value from the query result to LEFT JOIN back to the Tour Details table field subvenue. The join is returning the cartesian product (if it's still called that, sorry, I'm old...) along with the sum results.

I created a table using VARCHAR(100) for all the string fields and INTEGER for all the number fields. I'm not sure what RDBMS you're using but my dev database is postgres so the syntax is slightly different (namely, the string concatenation operator is '||' rather than '+' but I think the SQL you're looking for is along the lines of:

```
select 'Tours '||subvenue,sum(tours) from tourdetails group by subvenue;
```

I created a view with it like this:

```
create view subvenuesummary as (
select 'Tours '||subvenue,sum(tours) from tourdetails group by subvenue);
```

And a table like this:

```
create table sumsubvenuetable as (
select 'Tours '||subvenue,sum(tours) from tourdetails group by subvenue);
```

Both work fine and I'm sure the syntax would be similar enough in your database.

Comment: `||` is not a T-SQL operator.

Comment: Yes. As I said, the syntax is slightly different. It's the concatenation operator in postrgres. But you'd only need to replace it with + (I think) for it to work. The DDL / SQL is standard enough.